# Using horizontal scroll cards in mobile using ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, horizontal-scrolling

I am just starting with ionic. I am trying to use the Ionic Horizontal Scroll Cards. It looks like this, codepen: http://codepen.io/drewrygh/pen/jEJGLx

Now when i am using it in a template which has this structure:

```
<ion-view title="Videos">
    <ion-content>
            <hscroller>
                <hcard ng-repeat="item in items" index="{{$index}}" desc="{{item.desc}}" image="{{item.image}}"></hcard>
            </hscroller>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

But the scroll doesn't work on mobile, while searching i found that the hscroller element should be placed inside an ion-pane. But when i do that the list appears for a micro second and then disappears. I can't figure out why.
code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWRzPj
Here i have just added `<ion-content> and <ion-pane>` tags around hscroller.

Comment: (note: Chrome/Firefox DevTools must be used to emulate a mobile device when viewing the Codepen example.) ref. [here](https://github.com/drewrygh/ionic-ion-horizontal-scroll-cards#examples).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `<ion-scroll>` with horizontal scroll. You can easily create horizontal card view with that.

PS: the last code pen you provided. You needed to add

```
.scroll{
    height:100%
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwOoWd)

Though this does not solve the scroll issue, for that I suggest the above.

[ion-scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/)

Answer (score 1):

ion-scroll have support for horizonal scrolling.

Use

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" style="white-space: nowrap"></ion-scroll>
```

to replace your code

```
<hscroller></hscroller>
```